# window.top.opener not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have set of HTML files as follows:

```
first.html
second.html 
third.html
fourth.html
```

In `first.html` there is button on clicking that button `second.html` gets launched.
In `second.html` there is frameset in which loads `third.html`.
`third.html` has button on clicking that button `fourth.html` gets launched.

Now my question is from `fourth.html`, how can I get a reference to third.html  using `window.top.opener`?

Comment: Have you tried this `window.parent`?

Comment: window.parent is giving me the same fourth.html which should not be the case.

Comment: since from third.html I opening fourth.html using window.open("fourth.html") so I don't think it will work.

Comment: my results are as follows:
window.parent.location = fourth.html
window.opener = undefined
window.parent.opener = undefined

Comment: Is `fourth.html` in a popup window? Or does `fourth.html` replace `third.html` in the window?

Comment: Do buttons open popups ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.opener` refers to original window that created the current window with the current page. It is mainly useful for dealing with popups. In the popup HTML file, you call `window.opener` to get to the window that created the popup.

So if `third.html` created a popup window in which `fourth.html` is called, `window.opener` refers to `second.html` window.

Here is what you should get from `fourth.html` :

- `window` = current window
- `window.top` = current window trop frameset -> so it's the same since `fourth.html` is not in a frameset
- `window.top.opener` = window of `second.html` frameset
- `window.top.opener.thirdframe` = the frame of `third.html` you are looking for.
- `window.opener.thirdframe` = should be the same as `window.top.opener.thirdframe`

So you have to check that your `third.html` frame as a attribute `name` in your frameset definition :

```
<FRAME src="third.html" name="thirdframe">
```

From this you should be able to handle `thridframe` content or location etc.

Here is some [old school documentation](http://oopweb.com/JavaScript/Documents/jsintro/Volume/part3/part3.htm) about accessing frames.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I just tried it with dummy HTML files and it worked properly.

Now my problem is, third.html has a flash movie with a button, on click event of that button the fourth.html gets open up by using "ExternalInterface.call("window.open","fourth.html")".

If I go by this method it doesn't work. What could be the problem.

Comment: The real problem is that Flash is so 90's. Apart from that, it is probably that the `opener` property is not set properly by Flash. Maybe you can try that: create a Javascript `function open_third() { window.open("fourth.html"); }` in the `third.html` document. And then make the Flash movie call: `ExternalInterface.call("open_third")`. I'm not sure but that might work.

Comment: hey hi !!
sorry for late reply I was out.
It is working with my LMS but not on Local. 
I guess ExternalInterface.call("") is working weirdly on Local.

Thanx again for answering my queries and solving some ancient doubts of mine.